# c++ multithreading - memory synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have two functions which are called by separate threads:

```
void SetPtr(T* ptr_)
{
   ptr = ptr_;
}
void Process()
{
   if(ptr != nullptr)
   {
      ptr->fun(); // fun() can call Process() again
   }
}
```

I know that `SetPtr` is called before someone can call `Process`, but because those function are called by separate threads a memory may not be synchronized, i.e. `Process` may see an initial `ptr` value or may try read a `ptr` which is not fully written. I can use `std::lock_quard` to provide a synchronization but I want to see other possibilities. What are other ways to provide a memory synchronization for that case ?

**Edit1**
How to synchronized memory (without mutexex) when SetPtr can be called anytime ?

**Edit2** `ptr, SetPtr and Process` belong to the same class, ptr is initially set to nullptr

Comment: How can you do any synchronization without mutexes?

Comment: How do you **know** `SetPtr` is called before someone can call `Process`? This is critically important, see ComicSansMS' answer which assumes that you have a ironclad, portable guarantee.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that SetPtr is called before someone can call Process

You are done.

The synchronization mechanisms that are required to ensure that the call to `SetPtr` indeed happens before the call to `Process` will also make sure that the pointer observed by `Process` will indeed be the one that was set by `SetPtr`.

The reasoning in standard-speak goes as this: The call to `SetPtr` in thread #1 *inter-thread happens-before* the call to `Process` in thread #2. This is ensured by some synchronization point `P` in your program. The write to the global `ptr` is *sequenced-before* `P` in thread #1 (because they happen on the same thread). Furthermore, `P` is *sequenced-before* the read on the global `ptr` in thread #2. Note that the compiler and hardware are not allowed to reorder either of these across `P`. The vital property here is that *sequenced-before* combines with *inter-thread happens-before*.

Hence, the write to `ptr` on thread #1 *happens-before* the read on thread #2. There is no data-race.

Comment: but where does it say that `ptr` is global?

Comment: @DavidHaim It is shared. I just assumed it to be global, it could also be a shared member or even a shared local. Doesn't change anything about the answer though.

Comment: Could clarify your answer giving some code snippet ? What exactly do you mean by P ?

Comment: @Irbis Anything that establishes an *inter-thread-happens-before*. Could be a mutex, could be the launching of a `std::thread`, could be something crazy with atomics. You tell me what you do and I can tell you if it gives the synchronization guarantee that you think you get.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, i already argued about this point with someone else a year ago. You can't guarantee that. For example, the scheduling might be done completely outside of Posix model - say, through calls to `poll` and `eventfd`. While one can expect those calls to impose memory barriers de-facto, it is not guaranteed anywhere.

Comment: @SergeyA There is truth in that. However, if you start mixing threading-models like that, you better know what you are doing. It is extremely difficult to establish a situation where the inter-thread snychronization applies, but the transitivity to the sequenced operations does not. It is downright impossible to do in pure standard-C++. Since there was no indication by the OP that they were doing something crazy, I assumed the absence of such Machiavellian constructs. In real-world C++ of course, one always needs to consider system-specific influences outside the core language.

Comment: @SergeyA One could also argue that the statement by the OP: "I know that SetPtr is called before someone can call Process" is defined in terms of the C++ standard, and hence must use a primitive guaranteed by the standard. What else would it mean?

Comment: @Arvid, that it is defined in terms of other synchronization available to OP?

Comment: if that primitive doesn't establish a happen-before relationship, is seems like the assertion that one happens before the other isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::atomic<T*>`

```
std::atomic<T*> ptr;
void SetPtr(T* ptr_)
{
   ptr.store(ptr_, std::memory_order_release);
}
void Process()
{
   auto _ptr = ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
   if(_ptr != nullptr)
   {
      _ptr->fun(); // fun() can call Process() again
   }
}
```

as you said, `SetPtr` is called before `Process` , so this design works with this approach. If `SetPtr` is not guaranteed to to be called before `Process`, `Process` may suffer from the *ABA problem*.

Comment: IIRC a global `std::atomic<T*> ptr;` is not initialized to `nullptr` unlike a regular `T *ptr;`, so maybe it should be `std::atomic<T*> ptr{nullptr};` to make the logic work.

Comment: Please consider also Edit1

Comment: Note that your `Process` function tries to load `ptr` twice for no good reason. And `ptr->fun()` does not compile.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin fixed

Comment: And `ptr` has an indeterminate value initially, which causes `Process` to fail.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin of course he needs to initialize the object correctly

Comment: @nwp: "unlike a regular `T* ptr`" ? No, a regular `T* ptr`  isn't initialized either. Both are Plain Old Data types without a constructor.

Comment: @MSalters Global variables are 0 initialized, so a global `T*ptr` will be initialized to `nullptr`. However, a global `std::atomic<T*> ptr;` [will not be initialized to `nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic).

Comment: @nwp: You just linked to a reference stating that zero-initialization does in fact happen?! Why are you then arguing it doesn't? As for global variables, there's a special rule for them so I didn't include those in " regular `T* ptr`".

Comment: @MSalters I thought global variables are neither static nor thread_local, therefore they are not 0-initialized, therefore atomic global pointers behave differently than non-atomic global pointers, which matters in this case. I should have written "unlike a regular global `T *ptr;`". Apparently compilers disagree, so maybe I'm just reading it wrong.

Comment: @nwp: Global variables have _static storage duration_, which is probably the source of your confusion. "Global" refers to the scope of their name, which is different from function-static variables whose scope is local to that function but otherwise have the same storage duration.

Comment: @nwp, I had long and productive discussion here about 0-initialization of atomics. It is not guaranteed to initialize member, so you are correct.

Comment: @MSalters, you are missing the fact that 0-initialization of **atomic** variable itself is not guaranteed to properly 0-initialize it's value **member** (though one can expect this to happen with a sane implementation).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to share just a variable of a scalar type (integers, pointers, enums) between threads, you should use relaxed atomics:

```
std::atomic<T*> ptr{nullptr}; // Do not forget to assign an initial value.

void SetPtr(T* ptr_) {
    ptr.store(ptr_, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void Process() {
    if(auto ptr_ = ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) // Load it once.
        ptr_->fun();
}
```

Relaxed atomics are the least expensive atomics available.

Comment: `std::...relaxed` is wrong here becasue if if `SetPtr` is called in the same thread as `Process` the compiler can alter the stores and loads! consider `SetPtr(somePtr);Process();`

Comment: @DavidHaim Just read documentation http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order: _**All modifications to any particular atomic variable occur in a total order that is specific to this one atomic variable**... Atomic operations tagged memory_order_relaxed are not synchronization operations, they do not order memory. **They only guarantee atomicity and modification order consistency.**_

Comment: Your own quote shows why relaxed atomics is not suitable here - they do not order memory.

Comment: @SergeyA I can only suggest reading that documentation: _std::memory_order specifies how regular, non-atomic memory accesses are to be ordered around an atomic operation._ There are no other variables involved here.

Comment: And I can only suggest the same to you.

Comment: @SergeyA Do you have anything of substance to say?

Comment: **They only guarantee atomicity and modification order consistency.** Don't know what else to say here.

Comment: @SergeyA It is clear that you confuse _memory ordering_, which is about _surrounding_ loads and stores, with _modification order consistency_ of _this particular atomic variable_. There are no surrounding loads and stores here, no memory ordering is required.